# Как разместить блоки строго по строкам и колонкам?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Подскажите, с помощью чего размещать так, как показано на картике?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

К примеру чтобы один блок занимал половину доступного строки, а на другой половине размещались еще два блока, и  т. д. 
С помощью чего это сделать? Как определять количество блоков в строке? 
 Пробовал делать через Flexbox, но что то не вышло. Думаю, здесь лучше всего подойдет Grid. Так ли это? Как будет лучше?

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, в этом случае двумерная сетка `css-grid` подойдёт оптимально

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

.block:nth-child(1) {
  width: 33%;
  background: #99d9e7;
}

.block:nth-child(2) {
  width: 67%;
  background: #fffafa;
}

.block:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50%;
  background: #00ff76;
}

.block:nth-child(4) {
  width: 50%;
  background: #fff5ee;
}

.block:nth-child(5) {
  width: 25%;
  background: #ffd800;
}

.block:nth-child(6) {
  width: 25%;
  background: #80ce08;
}

.block:nth-child(7) {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffb7c3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">1/3</div>
  <div class="block">2/3</div>
  <div class="block">1/2</div>
  <div class="block">1/2</div>
  <div class="block">1/4</div>
  <div class="block">1/4</div>
  <div class="block">1/2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.main {
background: #FFD0AB;
padding: 20px;
width: 597px
}
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  text-align: center
}
.flex-container div{
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow:1; background: #99D9E7">1/3</div>
  <div style="flex-grow:2; background: white">2/3</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow:1; background: #00FF76">1/2</div>
  <div style="flex-grow:1; background: white">1/2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="flex-grow:1; background: #FFD800">1/4</div>
  <div style="flex-grow:1; background: #80CE08">1/4</div>
  <div style="flex-grow:2.16; background: #FFB7C3">1/2</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал на флексах так: 
Всем элементам `.flex` в контейнере по умолчанию задать минимальную ширину `min-width` 50%, и для каждой другой ширины высчитываем значения с помощью `calc()`, чтобы всё посчиталось ровно

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 display: flex;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto;

}

.flex {
 border: 1px solid black;
 min-height: 75px;
 min-width: 50%;
 background-color: pink;
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

.flex_1_3 {
 min-width: calc(100%/3);
 background-color: green;
}

.flex_2_3 {
 min-width: calc((100%/3)*2);
 background-color: yellow;
}

.flex_1_4 {
 min-width: 25%;
 background-color: #17dbed;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="flex flex_1_3">1/3</div>
 <div class="flex flex_2_3">2/3</div>
 <div class="flex">1/2</div>
 <div class="flex">1/2</div>
 <div class="flex flex_1_4">1/4</div>
 <div class="flex flex_1_4">1/4</div>
 <div class="flex">1/2</div>
</div>
```